# Error When Response.Write Javascript Alert

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm trying to do a `Response.Write` to pop up a Javascript error message when the script reaches my `catch` block in my ASPX page (not in a code behind or a class).

Here is the code:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('ERROR');</script>");

    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
} expected
```

No idea why it's telling me I need a `}`. Everything has been closed, when I remove/comment out that line and put something else, I don't get any errors so obviously, it's not like I'm missing a closing `}` somewhere...

Why is this happening??

Comment: Are you sure you don't get this message somewhere else?

Comment: I'm 100% sure. When I comment out that line giving me the error, everything builds fine.

Comment: Listen to @ayilmaz.  "RegisterScriptBlock" is the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but @Ondrej Svejdar's answer worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you probably have this statement enveloped in

```
<script type="text/c#">
</script>
```

So the

```
</script>
```

in statement below is taken as ending the C# script block

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('ERROR');</script>");
```

I see two options - move this logic to codebehind or escape the script to something like

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('ERROR');" + "<" + "/" + "script>");
```

Comment: Awesome! You were right, it was because that line was in between my c# script block. The bottom line fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use [RegisterScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx). please read the text and the example. I am certainly sure that is what you need

Comment: I would really prefer not to add all those lines of code if I don't have to, but I may have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing single quote near language attribute, 
Try This:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('ERROR');</script>");
```

Comment: try -> Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('ERROR')</script>");

Comment: @FastTrack : it would help us to solve your problem, if you can share your code.